# Call Number not working on IOS - ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic3

i am trying to use call number plugin to dial a number when a button is pressed it works perfectly well on android but when i try it on IOS it doesnt work at all.

```
public callStaff () {
  this.callNumber.callNumber('08160135356', true)
    .then(() => console.log('Launched dialer!'))
    .catch(() => console.log('Error launching dialer'));}
```

is there something else am suppose to do specially for IOS?

Comment: Are you using `iOS` simulator or actual device?

Comment: tried it on both still not working

Comment: Any `console` errors?

Comment: put the code within `this.platform.ready()` and then try

Comment: How exactly it does not work? Does it do nothing or does it log an error?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was pulling the phone number dynamically for different stores using google maps.

What my mistake was that I was using a http request to pull the phone number.
http.get works for android but for ios its different. I read that using httpclient was a possible fix.

But!!
What fixed it for me was using google.maps.getDetails and then pulling the property that I wanted.

What could the issue for you is how your pulling in the data, or maybe you need to update the callNumber package.